# rename batch files in folder using a textfile

Tags: sed, rename, file-rename, batch-rename, mv

I have a folder of files that start with specific strings and would like to replace part of their strings using the corresponding column from textfile

Folder with files

```
 ABC_S1_002.txt
 ABC_S1_003.html
 ABC_S1_007.png
 NMC_D1_002.png
 NMC_D2_003.html
```

And I have a text file that has the strings to be replaced as:

```
ABC ABC_newfiles
NMC NMC_extra
```

So the folder after renaming will be

```
 ABC_newfiles_S1_002.txt
 ABC_newfiles_S1_003.html
 ABC_newfiles_S1_007.png
 NMC_extra_D1_002.png
 NMC_extra_D2_003.html
```

I tried file by file using mv

```
for f in ABC*; do mv "$f" "${f/ABC/ABC_newfiles}"; done
```

How can I read in the textfile that has the old strings in first column and replace that with new strings from second column? I tried

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat file_rename);do oldName=$(echo $i | cut -d $'\t' -f1);  newName=$(echo $i | cut -d $'\t' -f2); for f in oldName*; do mv "$f" "${f/oldName/newName}"; done ; done
```

Did not work though.

Comment: Your question title is backward. You want to rename text files from a batch file, not what your title states now. You should edit it to correct it.

Comment: The first column of the textfile has the original string of the folder's filenames and the second has what it should be replaced with. I am using this text file to rename files in folder

Comment: You are *not* renaming batch files from a text file. Your question is about editing content of a text file from a batch file. They're not the same thing. Your title doesn't match your post content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the result of

```
sed -r 's#([^ ]*) (.*)#for f in \1*; do mv "$f" "${f/\1/\2}"; done#' textfile
```

When that looks well, you can copy paste the result or wrap it in `source`:

```
source <(sed -r 's#([^ ]*) (.*)#for f in \1*; do mv "$f" "${f/\1/\2}"; done#' textfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and rename):

```
parallel --colsep ' ' rename -n 's/{1}/{2}/' {1}* :::: textFile
```

This will list out the rename commands for each line in `textFile`.

Once the output has been checked, remove the `-n` option and run for real.

For a sed solution, try:

```
sed -E 's#(.*) (.*)#ls \1*| sed "h;s/\1/\2/;H;g;s/\\n/ /;s/^/echo mv /e"#e' testFile
```

Again, this will `echo` the `mv` commands out, once checked, remove `echo` and run for real.